# Automapper ProjectTo<> not working with Count()

Tags: sql-server, automapper, asp.net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have an odd issue with `AutoMapper` (I'm using .NET core 3.1 and AutoMapper 10.1.1)

I'm doing a simple project to list and a simple projected count for total records:

```
var data = Db.Customers
            .Skip((1 - 1) * 25)
            .Take(25)
            .ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToList();

var count = Db.Customers
            .ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .Count();
```

The first line creates the expected SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [c].[Code], [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [c].[Website], [s].Name
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [Status] AS [s] ON [s].id = [c].StatusId
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=0,@__p_1=25
```

The second line, the Count(). Seems to ignore the projection entirely:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
```

The result of this is that any customer with a null `StatusId` will be excluded from the first query but included in the count in the second. Which breaks paging.

I would have thought that project should create something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [Status] AS [s] ON [s].id = [c].StatusId
```

Anyone know why the Count() is ignoring the `ProjectTo<>`?

**Edit**
Execution plan:

> value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Domain.Customer]).Select(dtoCustomer
> => new CustomerViewModel() { Code = dtoCustomer.Code, Id = dtoCustomer.Id, Name = dtoCustomer.Name, StatusName =
> dtoCustomer.Status.Name, Website = dtoCustomer.Website})

**Edit 2021/02/19**
Mappings plan:

EF entities -

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string Website { get; private set; }
    public CustomerStatus Status { get; private set; }
    
    public Customer() { }
}

public class CustomerStatus
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

ViewModel -

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping -

```
CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>();
```

**Edit 2021/02/20 - Manually Excluding Status**

As pointed out in @atiyar answer you can manually exclude the status. This crosses me as a work around. My reasoning is this:

If you execute this query, as the very root query:

```
Db.Customers.ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
```

You get:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [c0].[Name] 
AS [StatusName]
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [CustomerStatus] AS [c0] ON [c].[StatusId] = [c0].[Id]',N'@__p_0 
int',@__p_0=5
```

This shows automapper understands and can see that there is a needed relationship between Status and Customer. But when you apply the count mechanism:

```
Db.Customers.ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).Count()
```

Suddenly, the understood relationship between Status and Customer is lost.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
```

In my experience with Linq each query step modifies the previous step in a predicable way. I would have expected the count to build on the first command and include the count as part of that.

Interestingly, if you execute this:

```
_context.Customers.ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).Take(int.MaxValue).Count()
```

Automapper applies the relationship and the result is what I would have expected:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [c0].[Name] AS [Name0], [c0].[Id] 
AS [Id0]
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [CustomerStatus] AS [c0] ON [c].[StatusId] = [c0].[Id]
) AS [t]',N'@__p_0 int',@__p_0=2147483647
```

**Edit 2021/02/20 - Latest Version**

Seems behaviour is the same in the latest version.

FYI: We have a scenario where records are imported on a regular basis from another application. We were hoping to use the inner join to exclude the records that don't have a matching record in another table. Then those records would be updated at a later point by the import process.

But from the application point of view it should always ignore those records hence the inner join and the status being mandatory. But we will have to manually exclude them (as per atiyar's solution) using the where to prevent paging from returning blown out page count numbers.

**Edit 2021/02/20 - Further Digging**
This does appear to be a design choice by the EF team and an optimisation. The assumption here is that if the relationship is non-null able. Then the join wont be included as a performance boost. The way around this is as suggested by @atiyar. Thanks for the help everyone @atiyar & @Lucian-Bargaoanu.

Comment: Good question, I'm am excluding the 5 release. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: 3.1.12, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer: 3.1.12, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools: 3.1.12

Comment: As I cant move to 5.0, due to technical requirements. I will try rolling auto mapper back a few versions.

Comment: I don't think AM is at fault here :) Testing on 5.0 will at least tell you whether is was a problem that was fixed.

Comment: You can very easily replace `ProjectTo` with a LINQ query and remove AM from the equation.

Comment: ProjectTo modifies the query to provide information from related entities based on the mapping target type. Removing the ProjectTo makes it a vanilla query which works fine and doesn't not include the related tables.

Comment: You're missing my point. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what point your making? Removing ProjectTo<> removes the issue. because the issue is in the ProjectTo<> not Linq?

Comment: Added execution plan.

Comment: @Rtype  I can infer from your SQL query, but you should add your mapping config, just for clarity?

Comment: @atiyar, done! hope it helps, im a bit stuck on this one. Never seen automapper do this before.

Comment: How is AM of no consequence? It is modifying the Linq query to do the projection. I think perhaps you think this is a normal Map<> call? 

ProjectTo<> actually modifies the Linq query to pull in related fields in from other entities. As stated already, without AM it works fine.

Project<> is seeing that I have a related field being pulled in "StatusName", so projectTo modifies the linq statement by adding a Join. Then it pulls the Status name for the requested entity and inserts it into the view model being projected to.

ProjectTo<> is a different beast to Map<>

Comment: @Rtype So your second query produces expected result if you don't use `ProjectTo<>` and use manual projection with `.Select()`? If that is the case, could you share that manual projection query?

Comment: You can very easily write all that _without_ AM, that's why :) And then you get to the root of the problem. You're not thinking things through!

Comment: The problem is that you make EF think that `Status` is required, meaning that `[c].StatusId` isn't nullable and an inner join is justified. So either make `StatusId` not null or add a predicate to get `Custormers` that have a Status. Joins should never be used as covert predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code in `.NET Core 3.1` with `Entity Framework Core 3.1` and `AutoMapper 10.1.1`. And -

1. your first query generates a `LEFT JOIN`, not an `INNER JOIN` like you posted. So, the result from that query will not exclude any customer with a null `StatusId`. And, the generated SQL is same with `ProjectTo<>` and manual EF projection. I'd suggest to check your query and generated SQL again to make sure.
2. your second query generates the same SQL, the SQL you have posted, with `ProjectTo<>` and manual EF projection.

**A solution for you :**
If I understand correctly, you are trying to get -

1. a list of `Customer`, within the specified range, who has a related `Status`
2. the count of all such customers in your database.

Try the following -

1. Add a nullable foreign-key property in your `Customer` model -

```
public Guid? StatusId { get; set; }
```

This will help to simplify your queries and the SQL they generate.

2. To get your expected list, modify the first query as -

```
var viewModels = Db.Customers
                .Skip((1 - 1) * 25)
                .Take(25)
                .Where(p => p.StatusId != null)
                .ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(_Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .ToList();
```

It will generate the following SQL -

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[Code], [t].[Id], [t].[Name], [s].[Name] AS [StatusName], [t].[Website]
FROM (
    SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Code], [c].[Name], [c].[StatusId], [c].[Website]
    FROM [Customers] AS [c]
    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [Statuses] AS [s] ON [t].[StatusId] = [s].[Id]
WHERE [t].[StatusId] IS NOT NULL',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=0,@__p_1=25
```

3. To get your expected count, modify the second query as -

```
var count = Db.Customers
            .Where(p => p.StatusId != null)
            .Count();
```

It will generate the following SQL -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[StatusId] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You can still use `ProjectTo` and then you don't need the `Include`.

Comment: @Atiyar, awesome practical example, thank you! and I agree you can do what is done there, which is manually excluding the status. Will look into it more. I think this comes across as a work around rather than a solution.

Comment: After digging into this further it appears this is a design choice by the EF team. Thank you @atiyar for taking the time to provide a solution.